# C++ Basics to Starting a very simple GUI

Tags: c++, visual-c++, user-interface

I just acquired Microsoft Visual studio 2013 for my college so you know what environment I'm using. I have never done any visual elements with c++, I have with many other *easy* languages such as LUA via the iPad or python, so on and so forth. Main question is, where do I start, what libraries do I use. Just some direction would be a huge help.
Thanks Guys,
Rain Terminal

Comment: I'd love cross-platform because I do run mac and linux machines alongside my current windows laptop. May be easier to get some of the basics with the built in APIs. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

[Qt](http://qt-project.org/) is a mature C++ library for cross-platform GUI development.

Comment: Do you know if that's build into my ide or is it something I'm going to have to download, thanks by the way.

Comment: You will have to download it.

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ / MFC used by oops concept along with libraries for easier use. Start from below link hopes that helps.                         http://get111.blogspot.in/2013/06/oops-concept-on-c.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to create a GUI with C++.

Since you are on Visual Studio and Windows, you can use the methods offered by the system, functions like `CreateWindow` etc. There are plenty of examples online, Google it.

Visual Studio also offers the so called MFC (you have to start a new C++ project as MFC), that allow easy development of GUI by interacting directly with GUI elements (similar to Delphi IDE). But this is all for Windows only.

If you are looking for a cross-platform alternative, there is Qt as mentioned before.

Comment: "MFC" and "easy development of GUI" in the same sentence? I would say use anything but MFC if you want to develop a GUI. On Windows, today, I'd go as far and say just do the GUI in C# with .NET, with a C++ backend. That's the direction Microsoft has taken.